# What is the return value of a function that has not defined a return value?

Tags: solidity

The code is taken from [this smart contract](https://git.hsbp.org/Metaverse_Championship/PMC_Challenges/src/branch/master/Prequalification_Challenges/solidity/storage.sol)

```
        /// @notice Only the central admin should be able to store his life memory in bytes32.
function store_me_on_chain(bytes32 _data) public returns (string memory) {
    require(msg.sender == admin, 'Not admin');
    data_store = _data;
    data_set = asmbl();
    ds_to_Str = Strings.toString(data_set);
    return data = string("den_who_is_dan_");
}

/// @notice Generate number
function asmbl() public view returns (uint8 b) {
    assembly {
        let c := add(27, 16)
        mstore(0x80, c)
        { let d := add(sload(c), 255) b := d }
        b := add(b, c) }
    }
```

asmbl is declared without a return. But asmbl() is to data_set. What is the value of data_set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

data_set = b

when you define a variable in returns scope like - `function asmbl() public view returns (uint8 b)`, it returns variable **b**. So you don't need to explicitly write `return` just set some value to **b**, and this value will be returned.

when you define function like `function store_me_on_chain(bytes32 _data) public returns (string memory)` without initializing any variable in returns scope it means that you have to explicitly write return .